# Re-identifying elements in wordpress text editor

Tags: css, wordpress

Currently I'm working on a website for my company on Wordpress.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVVn2.png)

As you can see in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVVn2.png), the headings are uneven so I use additional CSS to edit. However, a lot of the headings and paragraphs have the same class name so I have to identify the heading as
`h3 id="bottom-header"`

After this, I could modify the "LTDx Hybrid" heading into this [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TLux.png)

Now I would like to adjust the paragraph under the heading, following the same steps as above, identifying the paragraph as
`p id="bottom-p"`

Then I add the additional CSS code:

```
#bottom-p{
position: relative;
bottom: 30px;
}
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D40KB.png)

As can be seen from the picture, after applying those lines, nothing changed.
It would be grateful if anyone can tell me where did I do wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: what is your expected result? do you want paragraphs aligned?

Comment: exactly. I want the paragraph on the left aligned with the one on the right

Comment: then try to give min height property to heading instead of bottom.

Comment: I tried the min height property and it actually pushes the paragraph further down the page, which is the opposite of what I want. 
But because of that, I then tried the max height property and it worked. 
So yeah I still thank you man.

Comment: i am putting it as answer please accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `bottom` please try `min-height` or `max-height` property

```
#bottom-p{
position: relative;
max-height: 30px;
}
```